# Analytical solution to $|\cos(ax) - (ax)^2| = c.$

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry

Is there an analytical solution for x to the equation $|\cos(ax) - (ax)^2| = c$ in the interval $x\in[-\pi/2, \pi/2]$, where $a,c \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$ ? I only found the solution numerically. Thank you very much.

Comment: Seems that only numerical methods can solve such equations.

Comment: To have a unique positive solution, we need $c>1$. If this is the case, may be, *approximations*.